# How can I merge N files

Tags: c, file, sorting

I have N files, in each lines of every file there are unique words and the word count, for example

```
file1      file2     file3  
the 2      black 3   red 4 
apple 4    tree 2    crab 6
snake 3    mantle 8  puppet 1
```

How can I merge these files in sorted order into a one file, thanks in advance, really need an idea.

```
void *doMerge(void* arg){
    int i,j,p = 0, k = 0;
    char*min = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
    FILE *f = fopen("fileFinal","w+");
    char **StringBuffer = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*R);
    int *IntBuffer = malloc(sizeof(int)*R);
    for(i=0; i < R; i++){
        rewind(temp2[i]);
        StringBuffer[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
        if(fscanf(temp2[i],"%s %d",StringBuffer[i],&IntBuffer[i]) == 1)
            printf("String is %s and int is %d\n",StringBuffer[i],IntBuffer[i]);
    }

    while(1){
        strcpy(min, StringBuffer[0]);
        for(j=0 ; j < R-1; j++){
            if(strcmp(StringBuffer[j+1],StringBuffer[j]) <= 0){
                strcpy(min,StringBuffer[j+1]);
                p = j+1;
            }
        }fprintf(f,"%s %d\n",min, p);
        if(fscanf(temp2[p],"%s %d",StringBuffer[p],&IntBuffer[p]) == 1){}
        k++;
    }

};
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort by word or by count?

Comment: Have you made any coding attempts so far? If so, please post your code so we can give some pointers.

Comment: I'm really sick of arrogant people here, I do spend many effort and there are always ideantical comment as yours. Really I said I need an idea, youre so funny.

Comment: Idea: Read the files into memory, sort, write to file. Really, no magic here.

Comment: If each file was already in sorted order, you could merge them into an output file while only keeping one line from each file in memory. But since the files *aren't* sorted, you need to read the entire files into memory, sort each file separately, and then merge them to an output file.

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to mention that my program sorts the files so they should be in sorted order, yeah I can read all into array and qsort them and rewrite back but it isnt efficient

Comment: So you have a program that reads the files into memory and sorts them?

Comment: I have N file pointers for those files, I tried to read 1 line and store them into buffer and pick the minimum to write to final file but since I dont know the number of lines, I dont know how to do

Comment: yeah I have threads that reads files and creates N files in sorted order, also they count the word numbers so at the end they create files like i wrote above but in sorted order with ther word counts

Comment: Ok, so if you have 1 line from each file, you pick the minimum and write to the final file. If the minimum was from `file1`, for example, then you read another line from `file1`. If there are no more lines to read, then you mark that file as `done`, and only pick the minimum from files that aren't `done`. When all the files are `done` then the program is finished.

Comment: Actually, I excatly try to do what you said, let me share the code of my mergerThread, one moment please, its on virtual box ubuntu need to get it

Comment: I added my code, so as I said, trying to do what you said, read one line from every file, find minimum and write, and get the new line from the file that i write its line into newfile and find minimum... repeat this process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(1)
{
    strcpy(min, StringBuffer[0]);
    for(j=0 ; j < R-1; j++){
        if(strcmp(StringBuffer[j+1],StringBuffer[j]) <= 0)
        {
            strcpy(min,StringBuffer[j+1]);
            p = j+1;
        }
    }
    fprintf(f,"%s %d\n",min, p);
    if(fscanf(temp2[p],"%s %d",StringBuffer[p],&IntBuffer[p]) == 1)
    {}
    k++;
}
```

That `while` loop has a number of different problems

1) `p` needs to be initialized to `0` before the `for` loop
2) the `strcmp` should compare `min` to `StringBuffer[j]`, which also means that
2a)   the `for` loop should be `for(j=1;j<R;j++)`, and
2b)   `strcpy(min,StringBuffer[j+1]);` should be `strcpy(min,StringBuffer[j]);`, and
2c)   the line `p=j+1` should be `p=j`
3) `k` is not used for anything and should be removed

But the most important thing is the `fscanf`. You should be checking that `fscanf` returns `2`. If not then the file is done, and you need to keep track of the fact that the file is done, and that file should not be checked in the `for` loop any more.

Comment: thank you for your advise much, so I will count the ended files, when the count reaches to number of files, I will quit the while loop

Comment: Yes, that is a good way to end the `while` loop. But also you need an array like `int done[R];` to keep track of which files are done. Which causes a little problem because the first `strcpy` may have to choose a different string than `StringBuffer[0]`. I think you can figure it out :) Good luck!

Comment: I guess it is about to over, its working now but need some arrangement :)